# Averaging random elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, mean

I have a list lets say of 4 items, I need to cut down that list to 2 by taking any two elements of that list and finding the average of that list.
This is the algorithm I came up with, I do not know how to write this in R.

1. choose an `x_i`
2. choose an `x_j` not equal to `x_i`
3. find the average of `x_i` and `x_j`
4. choose a new `x_(i+1)` and `x_(j+1)` as long as they are not equal to `x_i` or `x_j`

for example:

```
x <- c(2,4,6,8)
y <- c((2+4)/2,(6+8)/2) or c((2+6)/2,(2+8)/2) or anything similar to that.
```

Comment: Maybe `?sample` and `?replicate` can help

Comment: sample just generates the data, I do not want to generate, I need to calculate.

Comment: "calculate" is step 3 while "generate" is steps 1, 2, and 4 of your own list. Ignoring that fact, `sample` doesn't "generate", it draws from a pool of data that is already generated.

Comment: sorry, i was not clear earlier, you are right sample just draws it from the pool, it does not help me with what I need to do, that is why i could not use      'sample'  or replicate

Comment: `sample(x, 2)` gives two non-duplicated draws from `x`, which satisfies steps 1 and 2. `mean(sample(x, 2))` will average those two random draws. This satisfies step 3. `replicate(2, mean(sample(x, 2)))` will do steps 1-3 twice and satisfies step 4. This is what I was trying to guide you to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of closing this question as answered, we can use the following syntax to do what we need to do: `replicate(2, mean(sample(x, 2)))`

Comment: Does this satisfy *choose a new `x_(i+1)` and `x_(j+1)` as long as they are not equal to `x_i` or `x_j`*?  Seems like you would have to remove the ones you just sampled previously. Or maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff I thought that might be an issue as well, but based on the examples OP provided, *y <- c((2+4)/2,(6+8)/2) or c((2+6)/2,(2+8)/2) or anything similar to that*, I assumed that `c((2+6/2, (2+8)/2)` implied reusing numbers was okay. That obviously flies in the face of Step 4, but I made the assumption that it was a miswording.

Comment: brittenb, the numbers can be used again as long it was not used before. Thank you for your help.